# FileNotFound when renaming photo WP8

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-8, filenotfoundexception

Im developing a Windows Phone 8 app that requires the camera. I take the picture and upload the pic to the server by reading the `Stream` in the [`ChosenPhoto`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.photoresult(v=vs.105).aspx) property. Once the upload finish, I need to rename the file to match some local convention.
So I pass the [`OriginalName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.photoresult.originalfilename(v=vs.105).aspx) property to the method but when making the renaming a `FileNotFoundException` is thrown.

Here is the method that renames the file:

```
public static void SetDocumentFlag(DocumentFlag flag, string photoName)
{
    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(photoName);
    string filenameWithFlag = null;

    if (flag == DocumentFlag.Send)
    {
        if (!photoName.StartsWith(SEND_FLAG))
        {
            filenameWithFlag = "dsend_" + fileName;
        }
        else
        {
            filenameWithFlag = fileName;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!photoName.StartsWith(NOT_SEND_FLAG))
        {
            filenameWithFlag = "nsend_" + fileName;
        }
        else
        {
            filenameWithFlag = fileName;
        }
    }

    string nameReplacement = photoName.Replace(fileName, filenameWithFlag);
    File.Move(photoName, nameReplacement);// here throw the exception
    File.Delete(photoName);
}
```

I don't understand why the exception is thrown since the photo is being saved to the camera roll successfully. I can find the picture in the camera roll.

What am I missing?

Comment: side note: you should probably replace your hard-coded prefix strings with `SEND_FLAG` and `NOT_SEND_FLAG`, in case the constant values ever change.

Comment: Is the exception being thrown on the `Move` command, or the `Delete` command? Because after `Move`, the original file will not be there anymore (as opposed to `Copy`, in which the original will remain).

Comment: Its in the `Move` command

Comment: silly question, but are you sure the file 'photoName' exists when this method is called (and it is a full path, not just a file name)? i.e. the creation completed and there is not some streamwriter or other object still locking the file? Can you show the code that calls this method?

Comment: Before doing all the things, what i do its to save the file in with the value that the OriginalName gives(absolute path, checked by debugger) and thats the value I use to do the other things.